# /me/apprequests returns null "from" property

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

When I use Graph API to access user's apprequests, /me/apprequests sometimes returns null "from" property, like the following.

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : "xxxxxx_xxxxx",
      "to" : {
        "name":"xxxxx xxxxx",
        "id":"xxxxxx",
      },
      "from" : null
    }
  ]
}
```

This occurs for some users data, but not always. How come this happens? All apprequests are created in same way, using Fb.ui({method: 'apprequests',...});

Comment: It could be a bug in the API.  Is this situation reproducible?  If so, you should log the bug with facebook.

Comment: Yes, if the data returns null "from" property, it always returns null for the same data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to send bug report to facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a bug report and received an answer as follows.

> It's due to privacy checks on the user who sent the request, in some
>   cases (user deactivated their account, user removed your app, etc) you
>   won't be able to read anything, including ID, about the sender of the
>   request.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/337541152923169?browse=search_4f0ad280300830331054933